# Nodemailer and Gmail

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I'd like to send emails using Nodemailer and GMAIL but it doesn't work...

**Edit #1 :**

Code :

```js
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpPool({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: '***@gmail.com',
    pass: '***'
  },
  maxConnections: 5,
  maxMessages: 10
}));

var mailOptions = {
  from: mail, // sender address
  to: 'infoprintwithlove@gmail.com',
  subject: subject,
  text: message,
  html: message
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }else{
    request.flash('success', 'Votre message à bien été envoyé.');
    response.redirect('/contacter-printwithlove');
  }
});
```

**Error :**

```
{ [Error: Invalid login]
     code: 'EAUTH',
```

It seems that the password is incorrect, but on the Gmail web interface my password works perfectly...

**EDIT #2 :**

[image]

Comment: Please see my edited answer to include var smtpPool = require('nodemailer-smtp-pool');

Comment: Already included in my code, but not on the post...

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass in service = 'gmail' and user/password:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    pass: <your password>
  }
});

// Or using SMTP Pool if you need to send a large amount of emails
var smtpPool = require('nodemailer-smtp-pool');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpPool({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    pass: <your password>
  },
  maxConnections: 5,
  maxMessages: 10
}));
```

## Edit:

Your might need to "Allow access to your Google account".  Login to your gmail using browser, and then go to this link https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha to unlock it. You might need to use the same browser you just logged in so google knows which account you want to grant access.  After clicking "Allow" button, you should see the message: "Account access enabled.  Please try signing in to your Google account again from your new device or application."

Comment: Strange, I'm currently using both methods above for our servers, and both are working for us.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why the password doesn't work... This is the true password...

Comment: Please see my edited answer at the bottom to allow email account access

Comment: Even after going through the "Allow access to your Google account" step successfully?

Comment: Try these steps from google support page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754?hl=en

Comment: Ok so now it works better... Anyway I get one more problem, the "from" address is equal to the "to" address... So on GMail when I click on "Respond", I respond to my own email...

Comment: it's works,, thanks! :) 
don't forget for set less secure apps turn on :
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
and “Captcha Enable” :
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha - Unlocking my account did the trick! thanks

Comment: Still getting this error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer to this question, Use generated App Password instead to enable Less secure app access -

[Error: Invalid login: Application-specific password required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701936/error-invalid-login-application-specific-password-required)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Gmail users, it is required to generate an "App Password" from their google account.

Here's the official Google link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?visit_id=638127803263092494-135774243&p=InvalidSecondFactor&rd=1

Then just use that generated password in your auth as:

```
auth: {
    user: '***@gmail.com',
    pass: 'Put your generated app password'
  }
```