# Error: Invalid login: Application-specific password required

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i want send Welcome notification when user sign in using Cloud-Function with firebase auth
so i m using nodejs CLI and run the code

my index.js file
    'use strict';

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    // Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
    // For Gmail, enable these:
    // 1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
    // 2. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
    // For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
    // TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.

    const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
    const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
    const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: gmailEmail,
        pass: gmailPassword,
      },
    });

    // Your company name to include in the emails
    // TODO: Change this to your app or company name to customize the email sent.
    const APP_NAME = 'Cloud Storage for Firebase quickstart';

    // [START sendWelcomeEmail]
    /**
     * Sends a welcome email to new user.
     */
    // [START onCreateTrigger]
    exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    // [END onCreateTrigger]
      // [START eventAttributes]
      const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
      const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.
      // [END eventAttributes]

      return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
    });
    // [END sendWelcomeEmail]

    // [START sendByeEmail]
    /**
     * Send an account deleted email confirmation to users who delete their accounts.
     */
    // [START onDeleteTrigger]
    exports.sendByeEmail = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
    // [END onDeleteTrigger]
      const email = user.email;
      const displayName = user.displayName;

      return sendGoodbyeEmail(email, displayName);
    });
    // [END sendByeEmail]

    // Sends a welcome email to the given user.
    async function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
        to: email,
      };

      // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
      mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
      mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. I hope you will enjoy our service.`;
      await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
      return null;
    }

    // Sends a goodbye email to the given user.
    async function sendGoodbyeEmail(email, displayName) {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
        to: email,
      };

      // The user unsubscribed to the newsletter.
      mailOptions.subject = `Bye!`;
      mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}!, We confirm that we have deleted your ${APP_NAME} account.`;
      await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log('Account deletion confirmation email sent to:', email);
      return null;
    }
```

i refer this code [`https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js)

but after i ran the code i got error

```
    Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor i82sm13686303ilf.32 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1523:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:550:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData.chunk (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
```

i also Allow less secure apps From your Google Account
and also done 2 step-verification [image: Here]
but still got an error

I read all "Similar Questions" here in stackoverflow and I don't know if I need anything else or if I'm doing anything bad

Comment: Did you "Set the gmail.email and gmail.password Google Cloud environment variables to match the email and password of the Gmail account used to send emails" as explained at point #8 [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users)? Also, have you read this [page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=BadCredentials&visit_id=637199434095522275-3208292064&rd=2#cantsignin)?

Comment: yes i did  @ Renaud Tarnec

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you have enabled 2-factor authentication on your Google account you can't use your regular password to access Gmail programmatically. You need to generate an app-specific password and use that in place of your actual password.

Steps:

Log in to your Google account
Go to My Account > Sign-in & Security > App Passwords
(Sign in again to confirm it's you)
Scroll down to Select App (in the Password & sign-in method box) and choose Other (custom name)
Give this app password a name, e.g. "nodemailer"
Choose Generate
Copy the long generated password and paste it into your Node.js script instead of your actual Gmail password.

Comment: Just to say it worked for me. As I have '2-factor authentication' active in my gmail account, I had to go to *App Passwords*, in my account config, and allow Google to generate a 16 chars password for me. I then used this password in my application and everything worked just fine ...

Comment: Add an app password from here: https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Comment: In case, if you don't find "App passwords" under "Security" -> "Signing in to Google" panel, 
In https://myaccount.google.com/security, do you see 2-step verification set to ON? If yes, then visiting https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords should allow you to set up application specific passwords.

Comment: As a complement to @Abdul comment, 
it seems that "app passwords" has moved inside "2 steps verification", click on 2 steps verification, enter your password and you should see "App password" at the bottom.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use an application password for this purpose. This issue will arise when 2 Step verification is turned-on for your Gmail account. You can bypass it by using app password. here is how to generate an app password.

1. Select your profile icon in the upper-right corner of Gmail, then select Manage Google Account.
2. Select Security in the left sidebar.
3. Select App passwords under the Signing into Google section. You're then asked to confirm your Gmail login credentials.
4. Under Select app, choose Mail or Other (Custom name), then select a device.
5. Select Generate.
6. Your password appears in a new window. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the process, then select Done.

google doc : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhy-you-may-need-an-app-password

Answer (score 10):

Generate a password from https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords and use that password instead.

Answer (score 1):

In case, if you don't find "App passwords" under "Security" -> "Signing in to Google" panel, In myaccount.google.com/security, do you see 2-step verification set to ON? If yes, then visiting myaccount.google.com/apppasswords should allow you to set up application specific passwords.

Comment: myaccount.google.com/apppasswords, did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps.

1. Once logged into your google account, in the top right corner click on your account image. And click on 'Manage your Google Account'
2. Select 'Security'
3. Under 'How you sign in to Google' section click on '2-Step Verification'
4. Scroll down and click on App passwords
5. Give App name of your choice and click Create.

It will show the password in the popup. Now use the app password in your project.

Hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

UPD: You can't do this on localhost. I try. Because it's not a secure connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in Gmail, Enable  2-Step-Verification.

Then create App password & use it on SMTP

Answer (score 0):

In other not to repeat answers. I created the app password from Google and used it in my app(Django rest framework app), yet it did not work, silly me, I forgot to restart my server and after restarting my server it worked.

Big Note: after changing the app password on your application: RESTART YOUR SERVER.

Answer (score -2):

you may still get error if you are doing this on localhost,Because it's not a secure connection(http not https).here is how to solve

for that remove `secure: true` in the configuration when you create the `transporter` or comment out it or set it equal to false.

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71992598/2227743) rather than a new answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).