# Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

Since google is removing less secure app mode, I'm changing the password settings for my app (which is written in flutter/Firebase) from the actual google password, to a password which I generate inside the setting of my google account to give full access. So I set the password like that

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email=email gmail.password=passwort
```

I checked everything twice with

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

and now wanna tried. But the problem that I have is that its always saying

```
 Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
```

This is my  functions

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

const { email = "", password = "" } = functions.config().gmail || {};

const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
  `smtps://${email}:${password}@smtp.gmail.com`
);


const senEmail = async (email, subject, text) => {
  try {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `"-IMPORTANT" <${email}>`,
    to: email,
    subject,
    text,
  };

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error", error);
  res.status(501).send(`Fehler! `);
  return;
}
};

export { senEmail };
```

I have to say I don't use google sign in for my app. Is this maybe a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Invalid login: Application-specific password required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701936/error-invalid-login-application-specific-password-required)

Comment: @RJC Does that mean i have to past the passwort manually to the variable in like that $new passwort`instead of ${password}@smtp.gmail.com`
? Because i did excatly everything what the accepted answer say and its not workinh. He says also i need to copy paste the passwort in the scrpt. Is this that what he means?
)

Answer (score 3):

Ok I fixed it. What I did was first making sure to do all the steps which are written in this blog

1.http://help.warmupinbox.com/en/articles/4934806-configure-for-google-workplace-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa .

2.Then make sure that you redeploy the functions.

Comment: I had the same issue and the link did help but I think you can provide some important points along with the link to make sure future visitors can benefit even if the link would be dead.