# Sending email using ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to send a email from an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using gmail account `sampleEmail@gmail.com`. I noticed that the option to allow less secure apps was no longer available on gmail and whenever I try sending the email it does nothing, but no errors are thrown.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyPortfolioWebAPI.Data;
using MyPortfolioWebAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using System.Text;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Text;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;

try
{
    StringBuilder template = new();
    template.AppendLine("from  " + email.EmailAddress);
    template.AppendLine("Name  " + email.Name);
    template.AppendLine(email.Message);

    var Mails = new MimeMessage();
    Mails.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("sampleEmail@gmail.com"));
    Mails.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("thabisofakude40@gmail.com"));
    Mails.Subject = " test response ";
    Mails.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Text) { Text = template.ToString() };

    using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    smtp.Authenticate("sampleEmail@gmail.com", "Password");

    smtp.Send(Mails);

    smtp.Disconnect(true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Kindly assist

Comment: _"it does nothing"_ <-- This is demonstrably false: just run WireShark and you'll see that it most certainly is not doing nothing (and after you've run WireShark, please post the captured 
TCP stream's packets showing the SMTP transaction: we need to see that to understand what's going on. Also check your GMail settings and/or if they have any logs or reports of failed sends.

Comment: i tested it using ethereal and it worked fine but when i try using the gmail smtp no email is sent

Comment: [Ethereal was renamed to WireShark back in 2006](https://www.wireshark.org/news/20060607.html)... _why and how_ are you using a decades-old build of it?

Comment: Did you enable "less secure apps" like described here: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/ (search for 'Using SMTP')?

Comment: "less secure apps" function is no longer supported by google

Answer (score 0):

i got it i just had to enable 2 factor authentification on gmail

Comment: I had to generate custom password, not use real according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60718806/10907757) article along with 2FA.