# how to make mail verification with nodemailer in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemailer

I'm facing an issue with sending emails using Nodemailer. When attempting to send an email via Gmail, I'm encountering an authentication error (code: 'EAUTH'). The error message indicates that the username and password provided are not being accepted by Gmail's SMTP server.

Here's how my code is structured:

**sendMail.utils.ts:**

```
import { sendEmail } from '../config/nodemailer';

export async function sendVerifyEmail(email: string, token: string) {
    const verifyLink = `${config.server.url}/api/v1/verify-email/${token}`;
    const message = {
        from: config.email.from,
        to: email,
        subject: 'Email verification',
        html: `Please click <a href="${verifyLink}">here</a> to verify your email.`,
    };

    try {
        const info = await sendEmail(message);
        console.log('Email sent successfully:', info);
        return info;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

**nodemailer.ts:**

```
import nodemailer, { Transporter } from 'nodemailer';
import logger from '../utils/logger.utils';
import config from './config';

let transporter: Transporter | null = null;

const createTransporter = async () => {
    try {
        if (config.node_env === 'production') {
            transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                host: config.email.smtp.host,
                port: parseInt(config.email.smtp.port),
                secure: false,
                auth: {
                    user: config.email.smtp.auth.username,
                    pass: config.email.smtp.auth.password,
                },
            });
        } else {
            const account = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
            transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                host: account.smtp.host,
                port: account.smtp.port,
                secure: account.smtp.secure,
                auth: {
                    user: account.user,
                    pass: account.pass,
                },
            });
            logger.info(`Test account created: ${account.user}`);
            console.log(account);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to create a transporter:', error);
    }
};

void createTransporter();

const sendEmail = async (mailOptions: nodemailer.SendMailOptions) => {
    if (!transporter) {
        throw new Error('Transporter is not initialized');
    }
    try {
        const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        return info;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred while sending email:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export { sendEmail };
```

In development mode, I aim to use test accounts for sending emails. However, I'm unsure where these test emails are directed or how to access them for testing purposes.

Could someone provide insights on how Nodemailer operates with test accounts and where to locate these test emails? Additionally, any suggestions on how to resolve the authentication issue with Gmail SMTP would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info)` returns the url where you can preview the emails send using the test users. The `EAUTH` error probably originates from the fact that you need to enable "Less secure app access" for the given gmail account or you can create an application specific password as suggested in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715813/nodemailer-and-gmail).